# Using 'What' As A Relative Pronoun

Tags: relative-pronouns, optional-that

I have an issue where some ESL students frequently use 'what' in sentences like this i.e. 'It was the first cake what I tried.' (I always prefer 'that' to which in sentences like this.) I at first claimed that you can't use 'what' in non-interrogative sentences, which is not true and the students called me on it.

I only corrected this error in a lesson about determiners and quantifiers, but I'm thinking a separate explanation of relative pronouns is in order.

Do you have any suggestions for an explanation that would make it clear to them and nip this mistake in the bud?

Comment: Possible cross-duplicate: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107073/use-of-what-vs-that

Comment: The "what" in "I've eaten what you gave me" is a relative pronoun in a 'fused' relative construction, where it means "that which". The other use of relative "what", again in a 'fused' relative construction, occurs in "What mistakes she made were very minor", but "what" is not a pronoun but a determinative.  In other words, the relative pronoun "what" is not ordinarily allowed in non-fused relative clauses in Standard English.

Comment: *What* used to be used in place of *that* in informal speech (and I think more in the UK than in the US). It's use was considered a sign of a lack of education, but it was still used. It's something that simply isn't done very much at all in modern times. At present, it's, at best, unidiomatic. It simply looks wrong to many people.

Comment: @JasonBassford true and I explained this to them using a Dick Van Dyke thing.. but I think it isnt clear.. the use of 'what' in the sentence is a relative pronoun right? I think I shouldn't just correct the error but do a lesson on relative clauses and pronouns. These people want to speak naturally and that's just not how people talk these days.

Comment: @BillJ In the example I gave, 'that' would be more appropriate to use. Would it be a relative pronoun in that example? That is also a determiner, right?

Comment: Yes, "that" is fine, Strictly speaking, "that" is a subordinator, not a relative pronoun, but I wouldn't worry too much about that at the level of grammar you're currently teaching. Yes, that can be a determiner in, for example "That milk is sour"